# Comparing values in a linked list

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is my class

```
class Element
{
  public:
    comparegreater(Element* temp1, Element* temp2)

  private:
    int row
    int col
    int value
    Element* next
};
```

I have a linked list and I need help with a function which is suppose to compare the first element (int value) and second element (int value) in the linked list.

How do I go about comparing these two values? This is what I have tried so far which I am sure is wrong. I know the answer

```
bool Element::comparegreater(ElementPtr temp1,ElementPtr temp2)
{
  if (temp1 > temp2)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Start by thinking about `temp1->getValue() > temp2-> getValue()`. You can also overload the `<` operator btw.

Comment: @axiom what do you mean???

Comment: You are comparing the objects. Unless you define the `<` operator, this is meaning less. So you have 2 options : 1. write a function that returns the object's field that has to be compared. 2. Define your own `<`, that is overload the '<' operator ( operator overloading ). A little Googling or referring to your favorite `c++` book is the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I go about comparing these two values?

By comparing the values:

```
return temp1->value > temp2->value;
```